# Is there anything that blocks reaction in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

Does Svelte have anything that blocks reaction to prevent loops? I have a child component that is calling a function passed down from a parent, which in turn sets a value that gets passed down to the child as a prop. The potential exists for an infinite loop. I don't have an infinite loop, but I'm seeing Svelte refuse to react a change to that prop the component that initiated the change. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if im understanding this correctly, but from your description of your code, it doesn't sound like there should be any loops going on, because you're just running a function that changes a prop

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out and posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... Svelte only dirties each component once per update cycle... my circular component dependency resulted in two conceptual dirties but Svelte only reacted on the first one... the fix was to add `await tick()` between these to ensure that the second change is in a new update cycle. Bingo, it reacts properly now.